# vibed: Can't get routing work

Tags: d, vibed

I am trying to get to work very simple vibed [routing](http://vibed.org/api/vibe.http.fileserver/serveStaticFiles):

```d
void main()
{
    config = new Config();

    auto router = new URLRouter;
    router.get("/*", serveStaticFiles(roothtml ~ "\\"));    

    router.get("files/*", serveStaticFiles("./files/"));

    router.any("*", &accControl);

    router.any("/checkAuthorization", &checkAuthorization);
    router.any("/login", &login);
    router.post("/logout", &logout);

    router.any("/upload", &upload);    

    router.any("/test", &test);    
    router.any("/dbdata", &dbdata);  
    // ...
}
```

text file `123.txt` is placed in `Files` folder.

But when I access to `http://localhost:8080/Files/123.txt` I am getting `404` error.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Using `serveStaticFiles()` is a bit tricky. If the `URLRouter` matches the request path then it forwards the request to `serveStaticFiles()`. This function checks the request path against another preconfigured prefix. In your case the prefix doesn't match and no file is served. Configuring the right prefix helps:

```d
auto fileServerSettings = new HTTPFileServerSettings;
fileServerSettings.serverPathPrefix = "/files/";
router.get("*", serveStaticFiles("files/", fileServerSettings));
```

It doesn't matter if you use `"*"` or `"/files/*` for the route matching. It only influences which routes are forwarded to `serveStaticFiles()`.

Comment: so if I need to serve several urls like `/foo` `/bar` for different folders I should create two `fileServerSettings` instances?

Comment: Yes, because the `serverPathPrefix` is matched against the request path.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
router.get("files/*", serveStaticFiles("./files/"));
```

Comment: Remove the catch-all get route at the beginning!

Comment: @greenify not help :( http://img.ctrlv.in/img/16/08/07/57a752cc97b82.png

Comment: Does the official [example](https://github.com/rejectedsoftware/vibe.d/tree/master/examples/http_static_server) for serving static files work on your machine?

Comment: Yeah, I can get access to http://127.0.0.1:8080/gzip/index_large.html
Can it be issue that my code do not have `auto fileServerSettings = new HTTPFileServerSettings;` ?

What this string is doing: `fileServerSettings.encodingFileExtension = ["gzip" : ".gz"];` ?

Comment: but in example there is **two** index_large.html one in gzip folder, one outside.

btw, that work http://img.ctrlv.in/img/16/08/07/57a770085ea4b.png

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how routing works, but I got work next variant:

```d
router.get("/rasters_previews/*", serveStaticFiles("./files/"));
    // url would be localhost/rasters_previews/101_005329_2_0_02.jpg
```